# One parallax custom transition

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can I create just one parallax transition that's custom on my site (nice scroll, then bounce) -

eg. With an arrow that when pushed, with a transition, scrolls the user to the bottom of the screen and then bounces a little after reached there. So, as if it scrolled all nice then hit the footer and reacted

Comment: It does not appear that you have tried anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

consider the jquery callback to animate.

```
$('#content').animate({marginTop: '-5000px'}, 2000, function(){
    $('#content').animate({marginTop: '-4900px'}, 1000);
});
```

That would do it, of course making massive assumptions about your html and css. If you want a better example you should provide some code or make a jsfiddle.

By the way, parallax is one of those silly buzz words going around these days. You can easily do a parallax effect with basic experiments in percentage based margins. But don't confuse parallax with scrolling and bouncing back. Huge difference.

Comment: Updated/Improved Question is moved here with a bounty if anyone can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8457547/parallax-transition-with-subtle-bounce-between-two-anchors-divs