# Parallax transition with subtle bounce between two anchors/divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to have just one link on my website that links to the 'below-the-fold area' that I'll have a simple contact form at; the idea is to have that link do a nice transition similar to js parallax and once it reaches the below the fold area it kind of subtly 'bounces' a few pixels back up. (The space between anchors is about 800px)

My attempts in the code below, but it's still just being read as an anchor-point without any transition. (Should I be loading a different jQuery library, or load them in a different order?)

***Updated Attempt 12-16:***

**Calling in the head**

**Libraries being called:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
```

**Just About before closing head tag. (A few inline styles are right before closing `</head>` if matters)**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $('a').on('click', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();//stop the browser from jumping to the anchor
        var href  = $(this).attr('href'),
            oset  = $(href).offset().top;
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            scrollTop : oset
        }, 700, function () {
            location.hash = href;
        });
    });

    </script>
```

**Mark-up, CTA divs**

```
<div id="top" class="scrollpls"><a href="#bottom"><img src="http://www.mysite.com/imgs/down_btn.png" border="0" style="float:right; margin-top:200px;"></a></div>
```

*..and near bottom of doc*

```
   <div id="bottom" class="scrollpls"><a href="#top">
<img src="http://www.mysite.com/imgs/upsubway.png" style=" float: right;
    float: right;
    margin-right: -74px;
    margin-top: 700px;
}"></a></div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Hpegt/1/

**A fiddle created from an early Question regarding this function and states creating a style with the div height in it. Since declaring this for all divs as in the fiddle would break my layout, I tried it with a class**

```
.scrollpls {
    height : 500px;
    border :0px solid #000;
}
```

**What am I doing wrong here?** After I someday get this, I'll be trying to figure out how to implement an 'ease' with a subtle bounce back after it navs to the points.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are tons of built-in [easing effects if you include jQueryUI](http://jqueryui.com/docs/effect/#easing).

Try this modification to your fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/CzQXC/

```
$('a').on('click', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();//stop the browser from jumping to the anchor
    var href  = $(this).attr('href'),
        oset  = $(href).offset().top;
    $('html, body').stop().animate(
        {
            scrollTop : oset
        },
        1000,
        'easeInOutElastic',
        function ()
        {
            location.hash = href;
        }
    );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        // this should really be in a click handler, but just for an example:
        $('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#testtop").offset().top
        }, 2000, 'bounce');
    });
</script>
```

Note: the `bounce` parameter specifies the easing to use. This is part of [jQueryUI](http://jqueryui.com/demos/effect/) so you'll need to download that and include it on your page for the effect to work properly.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response! But I still can't get it, above is the updated Question of where I'm at currently.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason it took a few minutes to function after I put the code in, but finally it resolved and I think this was the solution:

```
#top, #bottom {
    height : 130px;
    border : 0px solid #000;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Comment: I bet you'll have a better chance of getting help on this if you un-accept your own answer. People may look at this question as answered with that big green check mark there.